# Express the principal value of $z=i^{3+i}$ in the form $a+bi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Ok so I solved this but the answer given in the back of the book says something different. However, I checked my work and I don't see where I might have gone wrong.

$$z=i^{3+i}$$
$$e^z=e^{(3+i)Ln(i)}$$
$$e^z=e^{(3+i)(i\pi/2)}$$
$$z=(3+i)(i\pi/2)$$
$$z=-\pi /2+3i\pi /2$$

The answer given is $0.20788i$...how did they get that?

Comment: $e^{(3+i)\ln(i)}=z$, not $e^{z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Then

$i^{3+i} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+i\frac{3\pi}{2}} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}} = -ie^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} = -0.2079i$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $i^{3+i}=i^3\cdot i^i$ , but $i^3=-i$ and $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}e^{-2k\pi}$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.